# Changing color of commented text in textbox in windows application

Tags: c#, sql

Here is the code for changing the color of commented query:

```
private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(TextBox1.Text.startswith("--")||TextBox1.Text.startswith("//"))
   {
      TextBox1.ForeColor = Color.gray;    {need to modify for correct functionality)
   }
}
```

**Example:**  `-- select * from tab;
select * from table1`

The query getting changed its color, but when I try to write another query below that even the next query coming up with the same gray color,

How to change only particular selected text starts with (-- or  // )

Comment: What is this? WPF? WinForms? ASP.Net? It works as expected because your textbox.text will always start with -- or //. You might want to look at setting the color for specific text items

Comment: You need to use selectedText or selectedTextLength to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you set Textbox attribute  the line breaks are preverved:

In code behind:

```
private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String[] Lines = TextBox1.Split('\n'); //get all lines
}
```

But you have to remember that when you set

```
TextBox1.ForeColor = Color.gray
```

all Textbox contents will have gray color (you cannot set it for one line only).